# Багаточисельний чи численний?

Tags: різниця-між-словами

Знайшла у газеті: «Зібрання було багаточисельне». На сайті "Як ми говоримо" пояснюють: автор хотів підкреслити велику кількість людей. Але цього слова нема в українській мові, є прикметник численний. 
   Та якщо в публістиці його все-таки використали?..

Answer (score 1):

Слова "багаточисельний" **НЕ** містять:

ані [Академічний тлумачний словник (1970—1980) в 11 томах](http://sum.in.ua/s/baghatochyseljnyj)

ані [СЛОВНИК УКРАЇНСЬКОЇ МОВИ ONLINE.ТОМИ 1-8. (А-МІШУ́РНИЙ)](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=192564&page=95),

ані [Словники України Онлайн фонду НАН України](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/),

ані [Російсько-українські словники](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) (тут і Грінченка, і Єфремова, і ще купа),

ані [Англійсько-українські словники](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on).

Антоненко-Давидович і сам пише:

> Інколи трапляється в наших газетах і такий **дивний** прикметник: «Мітинґ
>   був багаточисельний». Слова багаточисельний, яким автор газетної
>   замітки хотів підкреслити, що на мітинзі було багато людей, **нема в
>   українській мові**, є прикметник **численний, який і треба було тут
>   написати**: «Мітинґ був **численний**». Якщо авторові хотілось посилити
>   враження, він міг би додати: **дуже (вельми) численний**.

Все однозначно: всі словники й лінґвісти кажуть вам, що прикметник "**численний**" використовувати **можна**, а "**багаточисельний**" - **ні**. Якщо вам на тому залежить - у своїх блоґах, стрічках, коментарях можете писати як хочете, але там, де потрібна літературна мова, прикметник "багаточисельний" неприйнятний.